# How disable rest of the buttons from an array of buttons when button is pressed

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, uibutton

Im having some trouble with method .disable in swift code. I have an array of Buttons and I want to disable the rest of Buttons when the correct Button (Target Button) is pressed. My array is call Buttons! Here are the action for the Buttons.
I have to have different names in the Buttons? or I can use .count method?
Thank you and appreciate everything.

```
@IBAction func btn1(sender: AnyObject) {
    if answerNumber == 0 {
        cwLabel.text = "You are Right!"
        pickQuestion()
        Buttons.count

    } else {
        cwLabel.text = "You are Wrong!"
        pickQuestion()
    }
}

@IBAction func btn2(sender: AnyObject) {
    if answerNumber == 1 {
        cwLabel.text = "You are Right!"
        pickQuestion()

    } else {
        cwLabel.text = "You are Wrong!"
        pickQuestion()
    }
}

@IBAction func btn3(sender: AnyObject) {
    if answerNumber == 2 {
        cwLabel.text = "You are Right!"
        pickQuestion()

    } else {
        cwLabel.text = "You are Wrong!"
        pickQuestion()
    }
}

@IBAction func btn4(sender: AnyObject) {
    if answerNumber == 3 {
        cwLabel.text = "You are Right!"
        pickQuestion()

    } else {
        cwLabel.text = "You are Wrong!"
        pickQuestion()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you heard about the `tag` property? Send all the buttons to the same action handler, look at the tag, look at the answer, done. No need for separate action handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to disable all of buttons or upressed ones? You can use toggle

```
func toggleButtons(button: UIButton) {
    for (var index = 0; index < arrayButton.count; index += 1) {
        if arrayButton[index] != button {
            arrayButton[index].enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: disable the unpressed ones and leave the one is pressed on!

Comment: Payal Maniyar above wrote complete version try that one

Answer (score 1):

Use below line of code. It may help you...

```
for (var index = 0; index < arrayButton.count; index += 1) {
           let btn : UIButton = arrayButton[index] as UIButton
     btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleButtons toggleButtons(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        }

    func toggleButtons(button: UIButton) {
        for (var index = 0; index < arrayButton.count; index += 1) {
            if arrayButton[index] != button {
                arrayButton[index].enabled = false
            }
        }
    }
```