# Im having some trouble with my .enabled buttons swift code

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Im working in a mini trivia game, everything is working fine. The only problem right now is when the user finish answering the questions the buttons still enabled.

I have created a function to disable and enable `buttons` and my function for disable `buttons` is working in my `UIButton` action but in this case is not working, I don't know if I missing something or Im doing something wrong.

PS: Im kind new in swift code This is what I have:

```
 private func pickingRandomQuestion() {
    if questions.count > 0  {
        questionNumber = random() % questions.count
        questionLabel.text = questions[questionNumber].Question 
        answerNumber = questions[questionNumber].Answer
        imgDisplay.image = questions[questionNumber].Img

        answerA.setTitle(questions[questionNumber].Answers[0], forState: .Normal)
        answerB.setTitle(questions[questionNumber].Answers[1], forState: .Normal)
        answerC.setTitle(questions[questionNumber].Answers[2], forState: .Normal)
        answerD.setTitle(questions[questionNumber].Answers[3], forState: .Normal)

        questions.removeAtIndex(questionNumber)
    } else {

        finishGame.hidden = false
        disableButtons()
        //Here is my problem 
        //NSLog("Done")
        //NSLog(String(finalScore))


    }
}

@IBAction func btnA(sender: UIButton) {
    unhide()
    disableButtons()
    if answerNumber == 1 {
        endLabel.text = "You are Right"
        finalScore+=1
    } else {
        endLabel.text = "You are Wrong"
    }
}
@IBAction func btnB(sender: UIButton) {
    unhide()
    disableButtons()
    if answerNumber == 2 {
        endLabel.text = "You got it"
        finalScore+=1
    } else {
        endLabel.text = "You are Wrong"
    }
}
@IBAction func btnC(sender: UIButton) {
    unhide()
    disableButtons()
    if answerNumber == 3 {
        endLabel.text = "You are Correct"
        finalScore+=1
    } else {
        endLabel.text = "You are Wrong"
    }
}
@IBAction func btnD(sender: UIButton) {
    unhide()
    disableButtons()
    if answerNumber == 4 {
        endLabel.text = "You are Right"
        finalScore+=1
    } else {
        endLabel.text = "You are Wrong"
    }
}
 @IBAction func nextQuestion(sender: UIButton) {
    pickingRandomQuestion()
    hide()
    enableButtons()
}
```

Comment: show how you disable/enable the buttons?

Comment: [Here is the solution of previous similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240170/how-disable-rest-of-the-buttons-from-an-array-of-buttons-when-button-is-pressed/39240503#39240503)

Comment: My post is now update, there is the way that I use to disable buttons

Answer (score 1):

```
answerA.enabled = false
```

Do your problem disable function does not working?

Comment: my function disable buttons is not working after the random question function finish.